# Enabling Click event on a textbox using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable a textbox and click event of a button using jquery like this:

```
$("#NumberCalledTo").addClass("disabled");
    $("#NumberCalledTo").off('click');
    $("#NumberCalledTo").prop("readonly", true);
    $('#NumberCalledTo').tooltip({
        disabled: true
    });
```

Now I need to enable it on click of another button. I am doing it like this:

```
  $("#NumberCalledTo").removeClass("disabled");
            $("#NumberCalledTo").on('click');
            $("#NumberCalledTo").prop("readonly", false);

            $('#NumberCalledTo').tooltip({
                disabled: false
            });
```

but click event is not fired.

Please suggest how to fix it.

Comment: I think that there is some complex logic here! It may work simpler, you have just to make the input field active after clicking on that button.

Comment: What are you doing with `$("#NumberCalledTo")` when clicked.

Comment: if you disable a button you can't 'click' it surely?

Answer (score 1):

`$("#NumberCalledTo").on('click');` is not enough, you need to bind the callback function again.

```
$("#NumberCalledTo").on('click', callback);
```

Comment: @DotnetSparrow It should be provided by you.

Comment: That is a function which works on click and i asked that to you too.

Comment: callback is the function that is executed when the event is fired. If you specified the behaviour of your button in the html (i.e. `onClick="someFunction()"`, then the callback is `someFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#NumberCalledTo").on('click', function(){
    alert('You click me!');
});
```

OR

```
$("#NumberCalledTo").on('click', callbackFunction);

 function callbackFunction()
 {
   alert('You click me!');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#NumberCalledTo").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        //ENABLE CLICK
        $(this).removeClass("disabled")
                .prop("readonly", false).tooltip({
            disabled: false
        });

    } else {
        //DISABLE CLICK
        $(this).addClass("disabled")
                .prop("readonly", true)
                .tooltip({
            disabled: true
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make a function:

```
 function enable(){
    $("#NumberCalledTo").removeClass("disabled");
    $("#NumberCalledTo").on('click');
    $("#NumberCalledTo").prop("readonly", false);

    $('#NumberCalledTo').tooltip({
        disabled: false
    });
 }
```

add as callback function:

```
 $('your button').on('click', enable);
```